# xml XElement showing null pointer exception

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am having the worst time with this, as I don't typically handle XML documents.

I have a long list of XML XNodes that I have gotten into a loop, and I need to store one particular element of the node in an array.

The problem is, though, I constantly have a NullPointerException and I am drawing a blank.

My code:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Items found: " + doc.Root.Nodes().Count());


        foreach (XNode node in doc.Root.Nodes())
        {
            XElement betternode = XElement.Parse(node.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(betternode.Element("loc").Value); //Null Exception here
        }
```

The count is showing 24,000 nodes in the document. The nodes are showing in locals, and when I copy the node content to W3 validator its saying the XML is well formed.

Node looks like this:

```
    <url xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <loc>http://url.to/my.jpg</loc>
  <image:image xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <image:loc>http://url.to/my.jpg</image:loc>
    <image:title>Huge spider</image:title>
    <image:caption></image:caption>
  </image:image>
</url>
```

So, since I know the node is there and valid,

Answer (score 0):

The `<url>` element defines a default namespace of "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9". So you need to use it when accessing the `loc` element.

You need something like this

```
XNamespace x = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
betternode.Element(x + "loc").Value
```

Another way:

```
XNamespace x = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
var locations = doc.Descendants(x + "loc");
foreach (var loc in locations) { ... }
```

Comment: I've been reading documentation for 3 hours and I have no idea what that even means.

Comment: if you only need `loc` element. you may consider to use xpath?

Comment: Also there is no need to reparse the node.

Comment: @RichardSchneider, thank you. I am not sure WHY that works, but it does, so back to the relevant documentation for me.